# Sort and return difference in an array task, returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

The function needs to take an unsorted array(ages) as it's parameter, then return an array of: smallest number, largest number, difference between them.

```
function differenceInAges(ages){
let firstArr = ages;
let sortArr = firstArr.sort();
let last = sortArr.slice(-1);
let diff = last - sortArr[0];
let ansArr = [sortArr[0], last, diff];

}
```

When the argument is passed to this function it is returning as undefined.

Comment: You don't have a `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I identified the following issues in your code.

1. No `return` defined.
2. `Array.sort()` performs only string sort. For numeric sort you need to define a function. (I have added that)
3. Using same array with assignment operator with out spread operator, this will copy same instance in `firstArr`, `ages`, `sortArr`

Hope this solution is what you are looking for.

```js
function differenceInAges(ages){
  let firstArr = ages;
  let sortArr = [...firstArr].sort(sortNumber);
  let last = sortArr.slice(-1)[0];
  let diff = last - sortArr[0];
  let ansArr = [sortArr[0], last, diff];
  return ansArr;
}
function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
console.log(differenceInAges([10, 20, 5, 25, 30]));
```